# Battery/cell circuit symbols

Tags: electric-circuits, conventions, notation, education, batteries

I'm teaching some younger kids physics, and we are looking at circuits.
When recapping circuit symbols, I remembered that there were different ones for a cell and a battery. A battery symbol looks like two circuit symbols in series... because this is exactly what a battery is.

Now I never before questioned why we have different symbols for these, but I am now.... what is the point? From a physics perspective, it doesn't matter whether we have a cell with voltage V and internal resistance R, or a battery with two cells supplying a voltage V and total internal resistance R right? Of course there is more place where we might have internal resistance, but for a poorly constructed cell vs well constrtucted battery it makes no differece.

Comment: "*A battery symbol looks like two circuit symbols in series*" Do you mean "cell symbols" here? To the question, I agee it makes no difference. Sometimes we tend to indicate the type of voltage source in a circuit, but it is strictly speaking unnecessary information as far as I know. One simple general "voltage source" symbol would be enough.

Comment: The symbol was dedicated to the cells but our understanding of battery as a combination of cells make us extrapolate the symbolto batteries.

Comment: A new question for you Then why do we say batteries(not an advance cell)

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Indeed, many people use these symbols interchangeably.